# AlpineJS and Webpack Encore (Symfony 5.2.x)

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, alpine.js

I started a new Symfony 5.2.x application which will have only some minimal javascript. For that, I decided to use AlpineJS. For the static files, I'm using Webpack Encore.

I read AlpineJS documentation and I even have an example for how instantiate a new AlpineJS instance. I'm not using `defer` property when I'm including JS.

Here's a part of my code:

**HTML**:
`<nav x-data="navbar()">...</nav>`

**app.js**:

```
import 'alpinejs';

function navbar() {
    return {
       ...
    }
}
```

However, when I'm refreshing the page, there's an error when I access the console log. "TypeError: navbar() is not a function". What should I do in this case? Have anyone tried to use this framework with Webpack Encore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this using `window.navbar = navbar;`, like so:

```js
import 'alpinejs';

function navbar() {
    return {
       ...
    }
}

window.navbar = navbar;
```

Explanation of this: bundlers (like Webpack) try to keep functions scoped to their modules, ie. not to pollute the global `window` scope. However when Alpine.js reads `x-data="navbar()"` it tries to find `navbar` in the global/`window` scope (ie. `window.navbar`), hence the fix.